# Does AWS SDK for Javascript work in a web worker (for performing Multi-part upload)?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, web-worker, aws-sdk-js

I was trying to use AWS SDK for JS to perform a multipart upload in a web worker. When i initiate a createMultipartUpload, I am able to see the uploadID in api call for incomplete multipart upload. But the createMultipartUpload is not returning the upload ID. Can we use the AWS SDK for JS on the web worker? and if so am I doing anything wrong here?

Code:

```
  a=s3.createMultipartUpload(params, function (err, data) {
        //Execution doesn't reach here
        console.log(data);
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        } else {
            uploadId = data.UploadId
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can encapsulate that into a promise :

```
        uploadId = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            s3Client.createMultipartUpload(initParams, function(err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    s3Client.abortMultipartUpload();
                    reject();
                }
                uploadId = res.UploadId;
                resolve(uploadId);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. I found that AWS SDK had some DOM dependency and was moving to error block after the successful request. Anyway I moved it out of web worker into a normal file.